# how to find result of matched query in php

Tags: php, mysql, regex

i am having one probelm cant cant figure it out how i can proceed. I have string like

```
  "Coolman United States Member Since January 2013 Loans  114.01 Active  66.00 Repaid    Credentials 2 followers eBay windchester 42 Friends 2"
```

now with php i need to find the user name that is "Coolman" country, member sience, loans, active, repaid, followers.

I know with preg_replace, regex i can find the exact text that is matched. but the problem is there are hundreds of data like this similar pattern, with different username with different countries, different dates etc so how can i have result like this?

username : Coolman
country:United State
Member Since: January 2013 and so on...

Thanks for your help

Comment: From where do you get such a string?

Comment: try with [mysql concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: what will be my separator as space are everywhere and how can select these strings where different length is present?

Comment: Is this data that you're inserting together as a string or are you receiving this from another source?

Comment: receiving from another source and i cant control that

Comment: One more question then I can give you an answer, Is the data always in this format? Is it always in this order? Is there a possibility that some of the values, say "Member Since", will not be present?

Comment: yes all data are in same format but information count may differ for example followers may have more than one but key pattern are always same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that may help you:

```
function GetBetween($content,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}

$string="Coolman United States Member Since January 2013 Loans  114.01 Active  66.00 Repaid    Credentials 2 followers eBay windchester 42 Friends 2";
echo GetBetween($string,"Member Since "," Loans");

$wh = strpos($string," ");
$username = substr($string,0,$wh);
$country = substr($string,$wh,strpos($string," Member Since")-$wh);
```

I assume here that the username is always one word.

Comment: thank you very much exactly what i needed, just can you help me how can get the user name? means here i can get strings between but how can get the first part before the country? also how can i get the country. sorry to bother...

Comment: ok, I will edit my answer in a minute.

Comment: @SamiaRuponti I've just edited my answer.